# Java Logger doesn't write into file

Tags: java, logging, io

I'm trying to configure Logger to write to a file in the application configuration folder, but I'm not able to figure how to do so, here is the function I use to configure the logging output at program startup:

```
private void ConfigureLogger(){
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FormLogin.class.getName());

    try{
        FileHandler handler = new FileHandler(getConfigurationFolder()+"\\application.log", 10, 1, true);

        logger.addHandler(handler);
    }
    catch(IOException e){

    }
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "test message");
}
```

The application.log file is created, but the test log is not written in it but in the console application.

Comment: getting rid of `catch(IOException e){    }` might help

Comment: can't do that, Unreported Exception error

Comment: so you have to fix that Exception first

Comment: @Joel replace `{}` with `{ throw new RuntimeException(e); }`

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try:

```
FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("D:/temp/application.log", 8096, 1, true);
```

### Parameters:

- pattern - the pattern for naming the output file
- limit - the maximum number of bytes to write to any one file
- count - the number of files to use
- append - specifies append mode

Comment: That works, but why can't I write to a file in the configuration folder (C:\Users\Joel\.application)? I already have a function that writes a configuration file in there and it works right.

Comment: Can you post your exact code on this? (or atleast the relevant part?)